# How to open Find and Replace task pane programmatically like office online using office.js?

Tags: office-js

I want to open the default Find and Replace task pane from Office Online on a button click from my Office Add-in(For MS Word).

[image: Find and Replace task pane in office online]

Is it possible to open the default Find and Replace task pane programmatically  using office.js or I do have to develop my own task pane? If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to trigger the Find and Replace pane from `Office.js`.

Depending on which host (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, etc), you may be able to programmaticly replicate the functionality. For example, you could use the [body.search()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body#searchsearchtext-string-searchoptions-paramtypestringssearchoptions) method and then iterate through the results. That said, this wouldn't be trivial and I'm not sure the value in replicating a function already baked into the app.

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to open that dialog with the API. Depending on what Office Application you are targeting you could do your own. Is this for Word? Excel?
If its for Word please check out the [following sample](https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/7bd7aec7d0b572caafd5ee1bc307e420) for [script lab](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380862&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false). Otherwise please clarify your question.

thanks!

Comment: Yest it is for Word.I wanted to trigger the default Find and Replace task pane and reuse it.Now I think I have to programmatically replicate the functionality.Thanks.